# How to access existing NLog MemoryTarget

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I'm reworking an existing logging system to use NLog Instead.  I've manually added a reference to NLog in my configuration file:

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="File" name="fileLogger" fileName="${basedir}\TRACE\${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.log" layout="TimeStamp:[${date}]|${message}" />
  <target xsi:type="Memory" name="MemLogger" layout="TimeStamp:[${date}]|${message}|${Type}" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="ApplicationLogger" levels="Info,Warn,Error" writeTo="fileLogger" />
  <logger name="ApplicationLogger" levels="Info,Warn,Error" writeTo="fileLogger" />
</rules>
```

What I want to do is in code pull out the MemLogger Logs and access the different parts (Type, Message, Timestamp).  How would I accomplish this?  I've seen how to create a new log from scratch, but I don't want to create a new memorytarget, I want to access the existing one in my config, pull the log data out of it, and then clear the memory (so that I don't have a memory leak).

How to I access the MemLogger MemoryTarget in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot access different parts of log. Logs stored as rendered strings, with all layout renderers already replaced with their values. All you can do is manually parse each log string. E.g.

```
var target =(MemoryTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("MemLogger");

foreach (string log in target.Logs)
{
    var parts = log.Split('|');
    var date = parts[0].Replace("TimeStamp:[", "").TrimEnd(']');
    var message = parts[1];
    var type = parts[2];
    //...
}
```

Comment: This worked correctly, but now i have a new issue.  How do I delete the messages out of "MemLogger"?  If I use target.Clear() it only clears the target instance, not the MemLogger itself, so I have a memory leak when I leave my app open for too long.  How do I clear out the actual MemLogger logs in order to prevent a memory leak?

Comment: @Fuzzerker logger holds references to targets instances which its configured to write to. Logger does not hold any messages. It just writes log events to all targets. If you clear messages from memory target, then these messages are gone and they do not stored elsewhere. Use some profiler to find where you have memory leak (I like Ants profiler)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("MemLogger");
```

Optionally, you can cast received target to `MemoryTarget` type.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to do this myself:

Natively:

```
IList<string> logs = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<MemoryTarget>("MyTarget").Logs;
```

or using a Cast:

```
IList<string> logs = ((MemoryTarget)LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName("MyTarget")).Logs;
```